# DBAccess::GetDBAccess().Execute(strcommand)... What is this line doing, use of dot here

Tags: visual-c++

I have this code in my application in Visual C++:

```
DBAccess::GetDBAccess().Execute(strcommand)
```

Here `DBAccess` is a class. What is been done in this line of code and what is the function of the dot operator (`.`) here? `GetDBAccess` and `Execute` seem to be functions since they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is method chaining, we are calling the GetDBAccess method and then, using the dot operator, calling the Execute method on the result of GetDBAccess.